# Winforms How to Bind to a List<long> DatagridView and have it show correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

So I need to show in a Grid a list of numbers that people enter to help them double check their work. It almost works except it doesn't show the numbers. My setup is simple. I have a textbox, they enter the number, when the add button is clicked its added to a BindingList and then that is used as the datasource for the DataGridView.

So, with some help from this [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform) I was able to get this halfway working.
Unfortunately, even though it appears to add a row the Grid each time it does not correctly show the value. **It shows the new rows as empty.**

Here is my code.

```
   public partial class ManualEntry : Form
   {

    BindingList<long> ProjectIDs;
    public ManualEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProjectIDs = new BindingList<long>();
    }
```

When the add button is clicked, this gets executed.

```
        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               long temp = long.Parse(textBox1.Text);
               ProjectIDs.Add(temp);
               ProjectsGrid.DataSource = ProjectIDs;
               textBox1.Text = "";//clear the textbox so they can add a new one.
            }
            catch//bring up the badinput form
            {
                BadInput b = new BadInput();
                b.Show();
            }

        }
```

And so here is the result of adding a few numbers.

[image: add project]

If you need any other code from me to help you answer the question, just ask.

Comment: I have also tried using a binding source as a datasource for the DataGridView, but I ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't told the DataGridViewColumn what to bind to.

Normally you bind to a public property of the bound data type. In this case your data type is `long` which does not have an appropriate property to bind to.

Wrap your `long` in a custom class and expose it as a public property.

```
public class Data
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

Bind your column to the `Value` property. You can do this in the designer, but here is the code:

```
Column1.DataPropertyName = "Value";
```

Now instead of `long` you use `Data`:

```
ProjectIDs = new BindingList<Data>();
```

...

```
long temp = long.Parse(textBox1.Text);
ProjectIDs.Add(new Data { Value = temp });
```

Comment: This sounds like an unnecessarily complicated way to do achieve this result. Could you show a way to just add the DataGridViewRow manually. I get an index out of range exception if I try       DataGridViewRow r = new DataGridViewRow();
               r.Cells[0].Value = temp.ToString();

               ProjectsGrid.Rows.Add(r);

Comment: have you added a datagridviewcolumn before trying this?
Like this:  dataGridView1.Columns.Add( new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() );

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett, remember that DataGridView is meant to show multiple information (=properties) of an object (=one row) in a grid. It is not just another ListBox. If you only want to show a single column, you might perhaps want to use a ListBox. As soon as you want to display two or more columns, it will not appear as an unnecessarily complicated way anymore...

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: basically what elgonzo said. This is a standard way to use the DataGridView, but If you only have a simple list of values, the DataGridView itself is probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The following post discusses this:

[DataGridView bound to BindingList does not refresh when value changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340192/datagridview-bound-to-bindinglist-does-not-refresh-when-value-changed)

It looks like your data type in the binding list needs to support the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

NOTE: Revised - my use of INotifyPropertyChanged was incorrect and also appears not to be needed.
Now this answer is basically just like Igby's - so I think his is the better one :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         ProjectIDs = new BindingList<AwesomeLong>();
         var source = new BindingSource( ProjectIDs, null );
         dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
         dataGridView1.Columns.Add( new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() );
      }

      BindingList<AwesomeLong> ProjectIDs;
      private int i = 0;
      private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         i++;
         ProjectIDs.Add(new AwesomeLong(i));
      }

   }

   public class AwesomeLong
   {
      public long LongProperty { get; set; }

      public AwesomeLong( long longProperty )
      {
         LongProperty = longProperty;
      }    
   }
}
```