# DataGridView bound to BindingList refreshes accurately, but not immediately

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I know this question is a lot like [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340192/datagridview-bound-to-bindinglist-does-not-refresh-when-value-changed), but still I can't figure out the answer.

Thing is, my class *does* implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and my grid *does* update... just not right away.  The values kind-of update in "bursts" instead of real time as each one changes.  The bursts are about 3 seconds apart, at which time a whole bunch of values update at the same time.  I'd like the grid cells to reflect the value updates immediately, and not in batches.  It's as if the grid is trying to improve performance by withholding a lot of individual changes in favour of waiting for a bunch of changes to accumulate before reflecting them in the UI.

My specific binding scenario:

- Winforms
- DataGridView
- grid DataSource is a BindingSource
- BindingSource's source is SortableBindingList of MyClass
- SortableBindingList inherits BindingList of T
- MyClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged
- BackgroundWorker threads make changes to individual properties of list items, with 5 threads running at one time

Update:

The answer is essentially this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

However, as this is a pet project with me as its end user, I don't feel like going to this length right now, so I've just caught the exceptions, and will put up with the slightly inconsistent grid update behaviour.  At least I see why it's happening.

Comment: My bet is the BackgroundWorker code, but you didn't share that with us.

Comment: There's a lot of code I could have shared.  I hoped for a 'direction' in which to focus, and you gave it - thanks!  It seems you're right.  If I make a bunch of changes to the list items outside the background worker, updates are 100% real time.  Let me dig into this some more, and then add the relevant pieces of code to the question.

Comment: I think I have some thread-safety issues with updating the data bound to the grid.  Now that I have more test code updating the properties, I'm seeing some occurances of "System.InvalidOperationException: BindingSource cannot be its own data source".  This *has* to be related, and may very well resolve the inconsistent grid updates I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement DoubleBuffer into Grid at the first line of your main module.
Something like this (code in VB.NET) - change  for the name of your grid control:

```
    <GridControlName>.GetType.InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", _
                                    Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
                                    Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or _
                                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, _
                                    Nothing, <gridControlName>, New Object() {True})
```

Comment: I'm afraid this made no difference.  It's looking more like LarsTech's suggestion - something to do with BackgroundWorker.

Comment: If the problem is related to the grid itself and/or the procedure to read data (including the data latency among hardware or network), the Backgroundworker won´t help and may create more delay. You need to identify exactly where is the bottleneck. Good luck!