# DataGridView will not update correctly

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I am currently working on a databaseproject, but my GUI won't update correctly.

My program currently has four DataGridViews. The first one contains all the bands.
The second one shows all bandmembers of the selected band.
The third one shows all albums of the selected band.
The fourth one shows all tracks of the selected album.

When I switch between two bands, the bandmembers and albums update just fine.
but here is my issue:

I have two bands. The first has already a couple of entries in every table.
The second only has the band itself.

So when I switch from band one to band two the track DataGridView does not update correctly and still shows the tracks of the first album. Like I said, the rest updates just fine.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MusicDB Context = new MusicDB();
    BindingSource bsSourceAlbum = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource bsSourceMember = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource bsSourceTrack = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AlbumDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.MemberDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.TrackDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Context.cInterpret.Load();
        BindingSource bsSourceInterpret = new BindingSource();
        bsSourceInterpret.DataSource = Context.cInterpret.Local;
        InterpretDataGridView.DataSource = bsSourceInterpret;
        InterpretDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        InterpretDataGridView.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        InterpretDataGridView.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        InterpretDataGridView.Columns["InterpretName"].HeaderText = "Interpret";
        InterpretDataGridView.Columns["InterpretFounding"].HeaderText = "Gründungsjahr";
        bsSourceInterpret.AllowNew = true;

        Context.cLabel.Load();
        AlbumLabelColumn.DataSource = Context.cLabel.Local;
        AlbumLabelColumn.DisplayMember = "LabelName";
        AlbumLabelColumn.ValueType = typeof(MusicLabel);
        AlbumLabelColumn.ValueMember = "Self";

        Context.cGenre.Load();
        AlbumGenreColumn.DataSource = Context.cGenre.Local;
        AlbumGenreColumn.DisplayMember = "GenreName";
        AlbumGenreColumn.ValueType = typeof(Genre);
        AlbumGenreColumn.ValueMember = "Self";

        Context.cInstrument.Load();
        MemberInstrumentColumn.DataSource = Context.cInstrument.Local;
        MemberInstrumentColumn.DisplayMember = "InstrumentName";
        MemberInstrumentColumn.ValueMember = "InstrumentID";
        MemberInstrumentColumn.ValueType = typeof(Instrument);
        MemberInstrumentColumn.ValueMember = "Self";

        bsSourceTrack.AllowNew = true;
        bsSourceAlbum.AllowNew = true;
        bsSourceMember.AllowNew = true;
        AlbumDataGridView.DataSource = bsSourceAlbum;
        MemberDataGridView.DataSource = bsSourceMember;
        TrackDataGridView.DataSource = bsSourceTrack;
    }
    private void InterpretDataGridView_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //bsSourceMember.Clear();
        //bsSourceAlbum.Clear();
        DataGridView SenderGridView = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (SenderGridView.CurrentRow != null && SenderGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem != null && SenderGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem is Interpret)
        {

            bsSourceAlbum.DataSource = ((Interpret)((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Albums;
            bsSourceMember.DataSource = ((Interpret)((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Members;
        }

    }

    private void AlbumDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bsSourceTrack.Clear();
        DataGridView SenderGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (SenderGridView.CurrentRow != null && SenderGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem != null && SenderGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem is Album)
        {
            bsSourceTrack.DataSource = ((Album)((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Tracks;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You tried `InterpretDataGridView.Update()` or `InterpretDataGridView.UpdateCellValue(i, j)` already?

Comment: Yes. It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem.
This is, what I added to my code:

```
    bsSourceAlbum.CurrentChanged += bsSourceAlbum_CurrentChanged;
    void bsSourceAlbum_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bsSourceTrack.Clear();

        BindingSource SenderSource = (BindingSource)sender;

        if (SenderSource.Current != null && SenderSource.Current is Album)
        {
            bsSourceTrack.DataSource = ((Album)((BindingSource)sender).Current).Tracks;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataBind()` method

```
InterpretDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: When I try to add that line, it tells me, that there is no definition...

Comment: please write no definition exception error for me to understand and help you

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

In `InterpretDataGridView_SelectionChanged_1` you are updating the binding source for 2 out of 3 of the other grids only, and these are the ones that you report as changing.

The binding source for the other grid: `TrackDataGridView` only gets updated from `AlbumDataGridView_SelectionChanged` - so try calling this just after setting `bsSourceMember.DataSource`.

Comment: This doesn't work either, since the `DataBoundItem` is from type `Interpret` and the tracks are updated through `Album`. Also, `AlbumDataGridView_SelectionChanged` is called when `InterpretDataGridView_SelectionChanged_1` is called.

Comment: So - `AlbumDataGridView_SelectionChanged` is not doing anything then?

Comment: It is doing exactly what it should do. That's why I am confused. When changing back to the band with tracks in it, `bsSourceTrack.DataSource = ((Album)((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Tracks;` has tracks in it, but they are not displayed

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340192/datagridview-bound-to-bindinglist-does-not-refresh-when-value-changed  ? There's a few different suggestions in the answers.