# Why Bindinglist is not updating after database changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, bindinglist

I am working in Winforms Projects. In which whenever I add or edit record in database and close that from I want my list updated.

But in Search Form my list does not get updated. For that I have to Rebind Data Again from database. When I searched and got know about bindinglist then I used bindinglist instead of list, but it is still not working.

Here is my code

```
///
/// Represent FirstName Fields
 ///
 public String FirstName { get; set; }
_MemberMaster.FirstName = Convert.ToString(txtFirstName.Text);
string result _IMemberMasterController.UpdateMemberMaster(_MemberMaster);
```

After update I closed my form, but in search form list not updating. As when list get updated I want datagridview get also updated.

Comment: Look into [BindingSource.ResetBindings Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings%28VS.80%29.aspx). Basically call `myBindingList.ResetBindings(false);` before closing the form. The true or false is: *true if the data schema has changed; false if only values have changed.*

Comment: @KeyurPATEL but mybindinglist is in searchfrom and i updated data in another form. And when i close EDIT MEMBER Form then i can go to SEARCH FORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem with IUNotifyProertyChangedEvent....

Answer (score 0):

I was about to reply in comments, but I want to give example code.

After the code to create a Form, for example

```
Form newForm = new Form(); 
newForm.Show()
```

or whatever method you use to make that form, add a formClosed event handler:

```
Form newForm = new Form();
newForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(f_FormClosed);
newForm.Show();
```

And then you can control what happens when the form is closed, so you can update your bindinglist easily.

```
void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    myBindingList.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

**Edit**

And in your bindingList constructor: (assuming it contains strings)

```
private BindingList<string> _mybindinglist;
public BindingList<string> myBindingList
{
    get { return _mybindinglist; }
    set
    {
          _mybindinglist= value;
          OnPropertyChanged("myBindingList");          // or RaisePropertyChanged or whatever you used
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said for **myBindingList.ResetBindings(false);** but this is nothing like **myBindingList.ResetBindings();** for binding list but its for Bindingsource and try both but still its not woking

Comment: Just to confirm, you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, right? Otherwise your bindinglist won't refresh when its changed. Reference: [DataGridView bound to BindingList does not refresh when value changed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29266719/6741868)

Comment: yes i am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in MemberMaster but just i am got know that PropertyChangedEvent is always null can yo tell how may i call that event in search form

Comment: Thank you for answer. Actuall My Proerty Changed Event was not firing now my Problem is Solved Thank you